# How to paste a comma separated string into one column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

For example, if I have (`bob, china, bing, bong`). I want to put `bob` on top of `china` on top of `bing` on top of `bong`.

Answer (score 1):

- paste **`bob, china, bing, bong`** into **A1** cell
- paste this formula into **B1** cell

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1; ","))))
  ```
- select **B1:B4** range
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`C`</kbd>**
- delete **A1** and **B1** cells
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`V`</kbd>** where you need it